# Modal Hide Doesn't Work In Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, show-hide

I have problem with hiding modal in bootstrap 4. 
In my tmp function I have to close modal after that I need use method update_table(url)

### HTML and JS

```
<div class="modal" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function abrir_modal(url) {
        $('#Modal').load(url, function () {
            $(this).modal('show');
        });
        return false;
    }

    function tmp(url) {

        $('#Modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $("#Modal").modal('hide');
        })
            update_table(url);


    }

    function update_table(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url
        })
            .done(function () {
                refresh_table();
            });
    }

    function refresh_table() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{% url 'Project:Task_Schedule_TableView' %}"
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                $("#_appendHere").load("{% url 'Project:Task_Schedule_TableView' %}" + "#_appendHere");
            });
    };
function hide_modal() {
    console.log($('#Modal').modal('name'))
    $('#Modal').modal('hide');
    console.log(33)
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I don't know what is wrong but when I try use the `hide_modal` function instead of the tmp function, modal is hidden.

Comment: the code in `tmp(url)` function state that when modal pop up is `shown` or `opened` hide it..

Comment: i check in console state is shown

Comment: `modal('hide')` would not work until show animation is done, thus is doesnt work right after shown event. The workround was to wrap hide inside `setTimeout`. But its mediocre.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code for **Bootstrap 4 Modal Pop Up** which hide the pop up.
You can check this..

```js
$('#Modal').modal('show');

function tmp(url) {

  $("#Modal").modal('hide');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal" id="Modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the pop up is shown call this function from browser console.. `tmp('http://test/test');` it will hide the pop up. It same as Bootstrap 3

Comment: when i cll tmp function in console i have that error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at tmp (<anonymous>:24:21)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
tmp @ VM5073:24
(anonymous) @ VM5084:1

Comment: have you added jquery and bootstrap js references

Comment: Yes : <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  and still the same

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Remove these lines from your code

```
 $('#Modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#Modal").modal('hide');
    })
```

**Step 2.** put the **hide_modal** function top of all code.
Then it will be appeared properly.